# XSLT for-each returning first element child only

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML which contains multiple customItems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <customItem>
        <CustomerName>1Test</CustomerName>
        <PONumber>321</PONumber>
        <CustomerProofRequired>true</CustomerProofRequired>
        <JobType>PVC Banner</JobType>
        <ArtworkDescription>TestB2Bconvert4</ArtworkDescription>
        <TrimSizeWidthinmm>5000</TrimSizeWidthinmm>
        <TrimSizeHeightinmm>6000</TrimSizeHeightinmm>
        <ChooseMedia>Bsmart PVC 510g</ChooseMedia>
        <BleedRequired?>true</BleedRequired?>
        <Replacementartwork?>false</Replacementartwork?>
        <MultiItemJob>Yes</MultiItemJob>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <SquareMetres>30</SquareMetres>
        <Price>120</Price>
    </customItem>
    <customItem>
        <CustomerName>1Test</CustomerName>
        <PONumber>321</PONumber>
        <CustomerProofRequired>true</CustomerProofRequired>
        <JobType>Vinyl Print</JobType>
        <ArtworkDescription>TestB2Bconvert3</ArtworkDescription>
        <TrimSizeWidthinmm>500</TrimSizeWidthinmm>
        <TrimSizeHeightinmm>500</TrimSizeHeightinmm>
        <ChooseMedia>Promotional (Budget Short Term Vinyl)</ChooseMedia>
        <BleedRequired?>true</BleedRequired?>
        <Replacementartwork?>false</Replacementartwork?>
        <MultiItemJob>Yes</MultiItemJob>
        <Quantity>7</Quantity>
        <SquareMetres>0.25</SquareMetres>
        <Price>1.75</Price>
    </customItem>
</root>
```

I'm using this XSLT to transform it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<field-list>


<xsl:for-each select="root/customItem">
<field>
<xsl:value-of select="ArtworkDescription"/>
</field>
</xsl:for-each> 

</field-list>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm only getting the first value "ArtworkDescription" in the result:

```
<field-list>
    <field>
        TestB2Bconvert4
    </field>
</field-list>
```

If I remove some of the elements from the input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <customItem>
        <CustomerName>1Test</CustomerName>
        <PONumber>321</PONumber>
        <CustomerProofRequired>true</CustomerProofRequired>
        <JobType>PVC Banner</JobType>
        <ArtworkDescription>TestB2Bconvert4</ArtworkDescription>


    </customItem>
    <customItem>
        <CustomerName>1Test</CustomerName>
        <PONumber>321</PONumber>
        <CustomerProofRequired>true</CustomerProofRequired>
        <JobType>Vinyl Print</JobType>
        <ArtworkDescription>TestB2Bconvert3</ArtworkDescription>
    </customItem>
</root>
```

I get what I'm looking for:

```
<field-list>
    <field>
        TestB2Bconvert4
    </field>
    <field>
        TestB2Bconvert3
    </field>
</field-list>
```

I cant figure out why, can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think `<BleedRequired?>true</BleedRequired?>` is allowed by XML, so I doubt you get the first sample fed to XSLT at all.

Comment: Well spotted! It works when I remove the question marks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question myself so it can help others from the scrolling-list level.

Thanks to Martin Honnen, who spotted that I had question marks in the element tags of my input XML. These are not allowed in XML and will cause an XSLT to fail.